# TypeError: 'KerasTensor' object is not callable

Tags: tensorflow

This code generates synthetic HVAC data using a Variational Autoencoder (VAE) model. The VAE is trained on original HVAC data, and the trained VAE is used to generate synthetic data that resembles the original data. However I get this error and I don't know why, here is the piece of code that have a problem with.  The error occurs in the line vae_output = MyModel(input_shape)(inputs=vae_input). Anyone can help with this?? thanks

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import joblib
import os
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.losses import mse
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from keras.layers import Lambda
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

data_initial = pd.read_excel('hvac.xlsx', header=None)


data = data_initial.iloc[0:96,0:3]


# Define the number of samples to generate
n_samples = 1000



class CastLayer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_type='float32', **kwargs):
        self.output_type = output_type
        super(CastLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.cast(inputs, self.output_type)

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape


# Define the VAE model
original_dim = 3
input_shape = (original_dim,)
intermediate_dim = 512
batch_size = 1
latent_dim = 10
epochs = 10000

x = Input(shape=input_shape)
h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(x)
h = Dropout(0.2)(h)
z_mean = Dense(latent_dim)(h)
z_log_var = Dense(latent_dim)(h)


def sampling(args):
    z_mean, z_log_var = args
    epsilon = K.random_normal(shape=(batch_size, latent_dim), mean=0., stddev=1.)
    return z_mean + K.exp(z_log_var / 2) * epsilon


z = Lambda(sampling, output_shape=(latent_dim,))([z_mean, z_log_var])

decoder_h = Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')

decoder_mean = Dense(original_dim, activation='linear', input_shape=(intermediate_dim,))

h_decoded = decoder_h(z)
x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(h_decoded)

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_h_decoded = decoder_h(decoder_inputs)
x_decoded_mean = decoder_mean(decoder_h_decoded)
decoder = Model(decoder_inputs, x_decoded_mean)


def MyModel(input_shape):
    inputs = Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = Dense(original_dim, activation='linear')(x)
    return outputs

vae_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
vae_output = MyModel(input_shape)(inputs=vae_input) # replace YourModel with the actual name of your model
cast_layer = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.cast(x, tf.float32))(vae_output)
vae = Model(vae_input, vae_output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh, In that funtion (MyModel) the return is the output not the model. So it's just a tensor, you can't call it.
You should do something like this:

```
def get_output(inputs):
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = Dense(original_dim, activation='linear')(x)
    return outputs

vae_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
vae_output = get_output(vae_input)
....
```